# Recycle View with month name

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

[image]

I want to create RecycleView like the image. There is a list of people's birthday. I want to show the month name in the left and name & date to the right side as shown in the image.

Comment: first tell me what you have tried so far ??

Comment: you need to use like https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: search section recyclerview

Comment: Please review the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Just put a textview in the recyclerview item layout(at left most corner ) and make it invisible. Whenever you encounter a changed month and the item is first in the list of birthdays in that month set the text of textview visible and set the text to name of that month .Otherwise make the textview invisible for rest of the case  .